# Phrase Request for the beyond or something hidden

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there any phase I would use to replace "Beyond" in my sentence below?

Beyond the flavorful taste, there are many health benefits of olive oil.

Comment: did you even try to look in a dictionnary for synonyms of beyond ?

Comment: @user82946: Welcome to the site! Where have you checked for synonyms of "beyond"? [Merriam-Webster](http://m-w.com) is one place I always check. Take a look there. If nothing seems to fit, edit your question to let us know what you looked at, what didn't seem to fit, and why. Then we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the flavorful taste, there are many health benefits of olive oil.

"In addition to," "besides," "aside from" are some other options.